# Input Field Accept only Numbers And Avoid Decimal Values from Entering

Tags: react-native, input-field

I have a `InputField` created using `reactNative` which is accepting the Decimal Value. How can I restrict user from entering the 'Decimal` in the InputField??Tried out with couple of solution from stack, none of it is working fine for me.

CODE:

```
<_InputField width="48%">
        <_NewProductTextBoxLabel>Minimum Quantity</_NewProductTextBoxLabel>
        <_NewProductTextBox
          keyboardType="numeric"
          returnKeyType="done"
          style={this.setBorder(0, 'min')}
          onFocus={() => this.setFocus(0)}
          onChangeText={text => this.setProduct('minimumQty', text)}>
          {this.state.newProduct.minimumQty}
        </_NewProductTextBox>
      </_InputField>
```

'ONCHANGETEXT CODE`::

```
  setProduct = (product, text) => {
    const newData = Object.assign({}, this.state.newProduct);
      console.log("SKT::::" + text),
      newData[product] = text;
        this.setState(
          {
            newProduct: newData,
          },
          () => {
            this.props.setEditedProduct(this.state.newProduct);
          },
        );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by the below code:

```
<_ProductDetailsRowView padB="15">
      <_InputField width="48%">
        <_NewProductTextBoxLabel>Minimum Quantity</_NewProductTextBoxLabel>
        <_NewProductTextBox
          keyboardType="numeric"
          returnKeyType="done"
          style={this.setBorder(0, 'min')}
          value = {this.state.newProduct.minimumQty}
          onFocus={() => this.setFocus(0)}
          onChangeText={text => this.setProduct('minimumQty', text)}>
          {/* {this.state.newProduct.minimumQty} */}
        </_NewProductTextBox>
      </_InputField>



setProduct = (product, text) => {
    const newData = Object.assign({}, this.state.newProduct);
    if (/^\d+$/.test(text) || text === '' ) {
      console.log("SKT::::" + text),
      newData[product] = text;
        this.setState(
          {
            newProduct: newData,
          },
          () => {
            this.props.setEditedProduct(this.state.newProduct);
          },
        );
    }
  };
```